# Redirect single HTTP URL to HTTPS via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, redirect

I created a new website. The old one used http and the new one uses https and has a a different URL path.

Example:

```
OLD: website.com/index.php/powerpoint-presentation

NEW: https://website.com/powerpoint-presentation
```

How do I direct a single URL in .htaccess this way? I would like to do around 10 manual 301 redirections.

Answer (score 1):

On the old web site in your .htaccess file you would use something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/powerpoint-presentation https://website.com/powerpoint-presentation
```

You may of course use as many as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Single redirects can be done like Dave mentioned:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/powerpoint-presentation https://website.com/powerpoint-presentation
```

But if all of your old URL's are structured the same way and you just want to remove the /index.php/ you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect any URL's with the old /index.php/ structure to the same URL on the https:// website without the /index.php/